# Not able to create new user for elasticsearch using elasticsearch-http-user-auth

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am not able to create a new user for **Elasticsearch** using **elasticsearch-http-user-auth** plugin. I want to create a user per index so that index will be accessible only for that particular user.

**Elasticsearch v5.1.2**

**Elasticsearch-http-user-auth plugin v5.1.2**

Added configuration in elasticsearch.yml according to the [doc](https://github.com/elasticfence/elasticsearch-http-user-auth)

```
elasticfence.disabled: false
elasticfence.root.password: rootpassword
```

Ran below commands to get the user list

```
curl -u root:rootpassword http://localhost:9200/_httpuserauth?mode=list
[]
```

For creating a user ran below commands but I got error

```
curl -u root:rootpassword http://localhost:9200/_httpuserauth?mode=adduser&username=admin&password=somepassword123
[1] 28647
[2] 28648
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ User already exists : null
```

[image]

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands

```
curl -u root:rootpassword "http://localhost:9200/_httpuserauth?mode=adduser&username=admin&password=somepassword123"
```

instead of

```
curl -u root:rootpassword http://localhost:9200/_httpuserauth?mode=adduser&username=admin&password=somepassword123
```